# Boost compilation errors

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to compile a topology library called `Dionysus` in C++. I keep running into a compile error related to the `Boost` library, but I cannot seem to figure out what the issue is? I have reinstalled boost a few times, and I am using version 1.62.0. I am also using `gcc` version 4.9.4.

The error message is below:

```
CMakeFiles/compare-diagrams.dir/compare-diagrams.o: In function `void boost::archive::binary_iarchive_impl<boost::archive::binary_iarchive, char, std::char_traits<char> >::load_override<boost::archive::class_name_type>(boost::archive::class_name_type&)':
/usr/lib/include/boost/archive/binary_iarchive_impl.hpp:58: undefined reference to `boost::archive::basic_binary_iarchive<boost::archive::binary_iarchive>::load_override(boost::archive::class_name_type&)'
CMakeFiles/compare-diagrams.dir/compare-diagrams.o: In function `void boost::serialization::throw_exception<boost::archive::archive_exception>(boost::archive::archive_exception const&)':
/usr/lib/include/boost/serialization/throw_exception.hpp:36: undefined reference to `boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
examples/alphashapes/CMakeFiles/compare-diagrams.dir/build.make:96: recipe for target 'examples/alphashapes/compare-diagrams' failed
```

The error seems to relate to the`/usr/lib/include/boost/archive/binary_iarchive_impl.hpp:58` but the file is there and all of the other files seem to be in place.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you install it from your repository? Or have you just added boost headers to the include path? because the error looks like the headers are there, but the compiled library cannot be found

Comment: I compiled the boost library using cmake. Should there be `*.so` files in that same directory?

Comment: There should be something, I'm not sure where. But it seems that it isn't forwarded properly to the linker.

Comment: Okay, I am recompiling `boost` right now. So if the compiled files are in the wrong directory, should I symlink or copy them to the directory specified in the error message? I would symlink unless there are like way too many files.

Comment: Okay cool. Got it working. I actually ended up upgrading my ubuntu from 14.04LTS to 16.04LTS. So that upgraded the ubuntu repos for boost. Then I was able to recompile `boost` and then `Dionysus` and it actually worked this time. Thanks for the help, I am not much of a C++ programmer yet, so I am not the best at decoding the errors.